# modifying the Linux file content

Tags: linux, automation

I want to modify SSH config file from command-line interface (CLI).

Initially file has :

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Should look like

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

I am able to replace the text using [**sed**](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) but couldn't modify. please help
Thanks

Comment: Did you want to tag the ActionScript 3 programming language? Doesn't _"able to replace the text"_ mean a kind of modifying was achieved?

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is a stream editor, designed to work on a stream.  If you want to edit a file, use its cousin `ed`:

```
echo '/PasswordAuthentication/s/no/yes/
w
q' | ed /path/to/file
```

Note that with some implementations of `sed`, you can use `-i` to modify the file.